# Converting from character to numeric in a matrix

Tags: r, character, numeric

I'm having some trouble converting my data types.
I currently have a matrix with 29 columns and I would like the first 25 to be numeric, and the last 4 to be character.

I've tried to convert the matrix to a dataframe using

```
pairMatrix = as.data.frame(pairMatrix)
```

and then converting the numeric to character using

```
pairMatrix[,25:29] = as.character(as.numeric(pairMatrix[,25:29]))
```

However, when I check the data types using `apply(pairMatrix,2,class)`, I get that they are all still numeric.

Just to give you some context regarding my code:

```
pairMatrix = matrix(0,nrow = 200,ncol = 29)  #numeric matrix
```

...Some numeric calc's in the first 25 columns...

```
pairMatrix[bothsides,26] = paste(rownames(decisionMatrix[bothsides,]),
                                 "a",decisionMatrix[bothsides,9],sep ="")
```

Where the last bit of code tries to add character values to the last 4 columns. This is where the whole matrix converts to character and where I become stuck trying to convert back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, been stuck with this for a while!

Comment: How about converting your matrix to data.frame before you add the character columns?

Comment: Matrix ELEMENTS ARE ALL OF THE SAME MODE! And if you use `apply` the first argument is coerced to a matrix. Use `lapply` to determine the class of dataframes.

Comment: @Sophia Thanks for the replies! I converted to dataframe, checked the types with lapply and found that the conversions were correct. Would you perhaps be able to help me with a problem regarding dataframes? I have the following code: `which(pairMatrix[,15] == 0)` (with pairMatrix now actually a dataframe). When I performed this operation before it worked find, but now it is returning `integer (0)`. I'm not sure if you maybe have to use a different operation on dataframes? Thanks again!

Comment: Your code should work, see this example:
`df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=c("a","b","c"))`
`which(df[,1]==3)`
But see the result of `which(df[,1]==4)`, so maybe there is no record with 0 in column 15 of your dataframe

Comment: @Sophia, that column does have zeroes. If I apply the same code to the same dataset when it is a matrix it seems to work. Not to worry though, I've found a different way of solving the problem without having to convert. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @Sophia.

Her solution: 
How about converting your matrix to data.frame before you add the character columns?